# Youtube Data API Reuse Access Token

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, access-token, refresh-token

I have been using the Youtube Data API, and every time that a user uploads a video to their account I generate a new access token using the refresh token that I store for each user.

I was curious, however, if I should also be storing the access token and only using the refresh token to generate a new access token when the access token expires?

Is this advisable?